# Temporary Table Value into a Table-Value UDF

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I was having some trouble with an SQL 2k sproc and which we moved to SQL 2k5 so we could used Table Value UDF's instead of Scalar UDF's.

This is simplified, but this is my problem.

I have a temporary table that I fill up with product information.  I then pass that product information into a UDF and return the information back to my main results set.  It doesn't seem to work.

Am I not allowed to pass a Temporary Table value into an CROSS APPLY'd Table Value UDF?

```
--CREATE AND FILL #brandInfo

SELECT sku, upc, prd_id, cp.customerPrice
  FROM products p
    JOIN #brandInfo b ON p.brd_id=b.brd_id
    CROSS APPLY f_GetCustomerPrice(b.priceAdjustmentValue, b.priceAdjustmentAmount, p.Price)  cp

--f_GetCUstomerPrice uses the AdjValue, AdjAmount, and Price to calculate users actual price
```

When I put dummy values in for b.priceAdjustmentValue and b.priceAdjustmentAmount it works great.  But as soon as I try to load the temp table values in it bombs.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 140
Invalid column name 'b.priceAdjustmentValue'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 140
Invalid column name 'b.priceAdjustmentAmount'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
--CREATE AND FILL #brandInfo

SELECT sku, upc, prd_id, cp.customerPrice
  FROM products p
    JOIN #brandInfo b ON p.brd_id=b.brd_id
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *
          FROM f_GetCustomerPrice(b.priceAdjustmentValue, b.priceAdjustmentAmount, p.Price)  cp
    )

--f_GetCUstomerPrice uses the AdjValue, AdjAmount, and Price to calculate users actual price
```

Giving the UDF the proper context in order to resolve the column references?

EDIT:

I have built the following UDF in my local Northwind 2005 database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_GetCustomerPrice(@adjVal DECIMAL(28,9), @adjAmt DECIMAL(28,9), @price DECIMAL(28,9))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT Level = 'One', AdjustValue = @adjVal, AdjustAmount = @adjAmt, Price = @price
    UNION
    SELECT Level = 'Two', AdjustValue = 2 * @adjVal, AdjustAmount = 2 * @adjAmt, Price = 2 * @price
)
GO
```

And referenced it in the following query without issue:

```
SELECT p.ProductID,
       p.ProductName,
       b.CompanyName,
       f.Level
FROM   Products p
       JOIN Suppliers b
           ON p.SupplierID = b.SupplierID
       CROSS APPLY dbo.f_GetCustomerPrice(p.UnitsInStock, p.ReorderLevel, p.UnitPrice) f
```

Are you certain that your definition of #brandInfo has the priceAdjustmentValue and priceAdjustmentAmount columns defined on it?  More importantly, if you are putting this in a stored procedure as you mentioned, does there exist a #brandInfo table already without those columns defined?  I know #brandInfo is a temporary table, but if it exists at the time you attempt to create the stored procedure and it lacks the columns, the parsing engine may be getting tripped up.  Oddly, if the table doesn't exist at all, the parsing engine simply glides past the missing table and creates the SP for you.

Comment: That did not work, still getting the exact same error.